# Error 0xE8003FFE while installing IPA file on device

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I am developing  an application(using Xcode 4.2 and iOS-5-SDK) aimed for iOS-4 as well as iOS-5. I can run my app directly from Xcode as well as by creating IPA file and then installing on iPhone 4.2. But problem arises when I try to run application on iPod touch that is recently upgraded from iOS-3.x to 4.2.

When I try to run application directly from Xcode, it simply gives messsage "running myapp on iPod touch" but actually app is not installed on device and no error message is shown at console. When I try to install IPA file of same app from iTune on iPod touch I get message  " Error 0xE8003FFE while installing myapp on iPod touch".

Do anyone has idea what might be the problem here? Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change architecture setting to armv6 & armv7 from armv7.

Answer (score 0):

check Entitlement.plist and "can_be_debugged" flag